# Rails Server [BUG]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get myself through the Odin Project.  One of the first lessons is to create a test_app for rails.  I have installed RVM and rails and everything is updated.

I am following the directions on this page:

http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_a_rails_app

However, I get this error when I run 'rails server'

```
Jessicas-MacBook-Pro:test_app lupinaccij$ rails s
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000418
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   for more details.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0032 p:-17581527583020 s:0113 e:000112 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0031 p:---- s:0111 e:000110 CFUNC  :require
c:0030 p:0020 s:0107 e:000106 BLOCK  /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3.rb:6
c:0029 p:0032 s:0104 e:000103 TOP    /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3.rb:2 [FINISH]
c:0028 p:---- s:0102 e:000101 CFUNC  :require
c:0027 p:0037 s:0098 e:000097 BLOCK  /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76 [FINISH]
c:0026 p:---- s:0095 e:000094 CFUNC  :each
c:0025 p:0055 s:0092 e:000091 BLOCK  /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72 [FINISH]
c:0024 p:---- s:0085 e:000084 CFUNC  :each
c:0023 p:0030 s:0082 e:000081 METHOD /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61
c:0022 p:0013 s:0078 e:000077 METHOD /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132
c:0021 p:0047 s:0074 e:000073 TOP    /Users/lupinaccij/railsbridge/test_app/config/application.rb:7 [FINISH]
c:0020 p:---- s:0072 e:000071 CFUNC  :require
c:0019 p:0014 s:0068 e:000067 BLOCK  /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79 [FINISH]
c:0018 p:---- s:0065 e:000064 CFUNC  :tap
c:0017 p:0031 s:0062 e:000061 METHOD /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76
c:0016 p:0033 s:0059 e:000058 METHOD /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40
c:0015 p:0116 s:0055 e:000054 TOP    /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17 [FINISH]
c:0014 p:---- s:0051 e:000050 CFUNC  :require
c:0013 p:0056 s:0047 e:000046 TOP    /Users/lupinaccij/railsbridge/test_app/bin/rails:8 [FINISH]
c:0012 p:---- s:0045 e:000044 CFUNC  :load
c:0011 p:0127 s:0041 e:000040 METHOD /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27
c:0010 p:0011 s:0037 e:000036 METHOD /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7
c:0009 p:0015 s:0033 e:000032 METHOD /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26
c:0008 p:0292 s:0028 e:000027 TOP    /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0024 e:000023 CFUNC  :load
c:0006 p:0122 s:0020 e:000019 TOP    /Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0015 e:000014 CFUNC  :require
c:0004 p:0159 s:0011 e:000010 TOP    /Users/lupinaccij/railsbridge/test_app/bin/spring:16 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0008 e:000007 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0020 s:0004 E:000b08 EVAL   bin/rails:3 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:0003d8 TOP    [FINISH]

bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
/Users/lupinaccij/railsbridge/test_app/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lupinaccij/railsbridge/test_app/bin/spring:16:in `require'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
/Users/lupinaccij/railsbridge/test_app/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lupinaccij/railsbridge/test_app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
/Users/lupinaccij/railsbridge/test_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/lupinaccij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require'
```

...

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
Jessicas-MacBook-Pro:test_app lupinaccij$
```

thanks!

Comment: Why are you reporting this here then? There's a URL listed in your post.

Comment: I fixed it by re-installing sqlite3.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by re-installing sqlite3.