# Rails not working anymore... I think I messed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I think I screwed up and now I'm stuck with this error message :(
How do I get out of here?

```
pedal@RN-145-97-138-125:~$ rails -v
/Users/pedal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in
`to_specs': Could not find 'actionpack' (= 4.2.1) among 62 total
gem(s) (Gem::LoadError) Checked in
'GEM_PATH=/Users/pedal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1:/Users/pedal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global',
execute `gem env` for more information  from
/Users/pedal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1311:in
`block in activate_dependencies'    from
/Users/pedal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in
`each'  from
/Users/pedal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in
`activate_dependencies'     from
/Users/pedal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1282:in
`activate'  from
/Users/pedal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in
`block in gem'  from
/Users/pedal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in
`synchronize'   from
/Users/pedal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in
`gem'   from /Users/pedal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rails:22:in
`<main>'    from
/Users/pedal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
`eval'  from
/Users/pedal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
`<main>'§§§§
```

Comment: What did you do to "screw up?" We need a little more information, my friend.

Comment: Did you recently update your Gemfile? Try `bundle install` to make sure the gems are installed.

Comment: I was trying to run "rails server" after just installed ruby and rails but a huge error message came up. (This one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357144/rails-server-bug)

Then I re-installed sqlite3 becuase that seemed to work for that other user and this error message started to come up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
gem pristine --all
```

Then

```
bundle install
```

In the terminal of project folder

Comment: I did that and this happened:
`pedal@RN-145-97-138-125:~/railsbridge/test_app$ gem pristine --all
Restoring gems to pristine condition...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/pedal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.1/CHANGELOG.md`

Comment: Oh, I think that managed to solve it. I just re-installed and now the server is running as it should. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the `actionpack` gem. Try (re-)installing it with `gem install actionpack`.